# Load survey results into SEDE!

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, survey

Why is survey results data not uploaded to SEDE under a new "site" called "Research" or "Survey Results" (or similar)?

If the data is CSV, surely a simple database schema can be created and the data loaded into it, plus another column for "year" so cross-year queries can be run.

Doing this would not only provide a powerful portal for the data, but it would also allow folks to share their queries and graphical results.

Comment: ... and if that was never the intention then the wording of the blog post shouldn't give that impression...

Comment: The survey was designed using spreadsheets and administered using a 3rd party system (never touched our SQL servers). The questions also change each year, so they don't fit in a simple schema. That said, this sounds like a great project for the community to get involved in. The new SEDE tutorial only happened because it came in as a community pull request.